# How is a varchar index stored?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, indexing

I'm trying to get an understanding around the implications of indexing a varchar column.  If the column was 150 characters long, how are the indexes stored?  For example,  I understand how a btree is used when indexing an int column, but a varchar is multiple characters,  is the index essentially a compound index composed of char[1], then char[2], etc?

To make the example simple, if I had values AAA,AAB,ABB,ABC, etc, what would the index structure look like?

Comment: You might get a better response if you put your question here, http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `varchar(150)` column values will be sorted alphabetically (defined by the collation you use), as strings (not as arrays of chars). So basically, in the end, you have one long list of sorted strings.

This list is then arranged in a balanced btree fashion. Each level of an index points down to another level, and the values of the index entries define which range of values is contained on each lower-level index page.

With this arrangement, with only a few page reads, SQL Server will reach the leaf level of the index and be able to get your data. So really, the strings are interpreted as atomic strings - not compounds of characters or anything.

Basically, the structure of the index will look at lot like the one shown in [SQL Server Index Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) - only instead of numerical values, you'll have string values in your index pages.